# How to copy and apply a patch/diff to a svelte file on build?

Tags: svelte, diff, vite, patch, sveltekit

I'm building a svelte npm module with sveltekit. It supplies components that are identical except for a couple lines. I'd like to generate one of the components based on the original. How can I copy a file and apply a patch/diff to it on build? Should I look into the svelte preprocessor, vite preprocessor and build, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually very easy to do :-)

Take this as an example:

```js
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { resolve } from 'path';

export default function () {
  return {
    name: 'my-plugin',
    load(file) {
      if (file === resolve(<target file path>)) {
        let code = readFileSync(<original file path>, 'utf-8');
        // Apply any patch required to `code`

        return { code, map: null };
      }
    }
  };
}
```

If this file was `myPlugin.js` then you just need to add it into your `vite.config.ts` like this:

```
import MyPlugin from 'myPlugin.js';

const config: UserConfig = {
  plugins: [
    MyPlugin()
  ]
};

export default config;
```

I have several of those plugins build like this and they work like a charm. By inspecting [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html)'s documentation, you can even do fancy stuff like returning some contents for the client and some other for the server etc.

However, let me make you a warning: as cool as doing this might seem, I've found that applying in-code solutions are far better than compiled ones since the compiled solutions not only feel like magic but they also diverge from the real source code so debugging it can become tricker (under those circumstances, the [`vite-plugin-inspect`](https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-inspect) has proven very valuable to me).

In your case, I would, perhaps experiment with abstraction or design patterns like the decorator. However, I'm unaware of your specific use case so take my advice with a pinch of salt.

That said, have fun!